# Testing Paypal Credit with Express Checkout

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I'm implementing PayPal Express Checkout and I'm having trouble testing out PayPal Credit as the payment method.  When I choose it as the method of payment, the response comes back as ERRORCODE0=10486 which means "This transaction couldn't be completed. Please redirect your customer to PayPal."  It works fine when using other methods of payment.

Does anyone know if it's possible to make test transactions with PayPal Credit?  I haven't been able to find anything in the docs or google about it so hoping someone on here knows!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have two options for testing. 
You can test it with the [PayPal Demo site](https://demo.paypal.com/us/home#/), which not only demos from start to finish paying with PayPal Credit. It also has working sample code available.

I found that you can simulate a PayPal Credit transaction in a sandbox account. I tested it on one of my sandbox accounts. You have to login in to one of your sandbox accounts that is not the merchant account that you are testing. I put in demo info when it asked me to apply for the product. My sandbox account was approved.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for showing me that, it helps a little, but I still am unable to get a successful test transaction to go through using paypal credit.  I get redirected back every time saying: 

"We're sorry, but we couldn't complete your purchase using this payment method. We've selected another method for you. You may continue with this method, or choose a different one."

Comment: Make sure you are pointed to Sandbox. Did you log in using your test sandbox account and use test information when applying for PayPal Credit? You can also download the sample code from the demo site for this and run a test using the sample to see if you have a coding issue.

Comment: Yeah, everything is pointing to sandbox.  I'm pretty sure everything is configured correctly.  It works fine when using any other payment type except for paypal credit.

Comment: Create a new business sandbox account make certain it is an US based account and give it a balance of $5,000. Attempt the payment by logging in with the new sandbox account use 1234 as the last four of the SSN and whatever birthday you want before 1989. If that still doesn't work. Download the code for PayPal Credit from the demo site and attempt a test with that code.

Comment: Thanks for all your help, but it still didn't work.  Tried it with the demo site code and my own.

Answer (score 0):

So I was able to get it to kind of work (at least in the sandbox).  The issue was that it seems like it didn't like me passing in:

"USERSELECTEDFUNDINGSOURCE" => "BML" (old version) or "USERSELECTEDFUNDINGSOURCE"   => "Finance" (new version)

When I used this option it sent me to a page that looked like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IP2xY.jpg

Which is what I wanted as we mainly wanted to focus on offering customers PayPal Credit.

When you remove the USERSELECTEDFUNDINGSOURCE option it takes you to a page like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SM5zh.jpg

If you choose change payment source on this page and choose PayPal Credit, the transaction goes through successfully.

It's not exactly a solution to the problem but hopefully this helps anyone who was also having a similar issue.